# Combinatorics on the word Abracadabra

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many different 'words' can be created using all the characters of '$ABRACADABRA'$? In how many of the 'words' that there are no identical characters one next to the other?

So, For the first part, the calculation would be $$\frac{11!}{5! 2! 2!} $$since there are 11 letters of which the letters $A$, $B$ and $R$ are repetitive.

But I can't quite figure out the second part of the question. Please help clarify it to me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a different approach.

According to Theorem 2.1 in *Counting words with Laguerre series* by Jair  Taylor, The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics 21(2) (2014) (here is a version of the paper at [arXiv.org](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6232)), the number of acceptable permutations is

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \; \ell_1(t)^2 \; \ell_2(t)^2 \; \ell_5(t) \; dt$$
where
$$\begin{align}
\ell_1(t) &= t \\
\ell_2(t) &= \frac{1}{2} t^2 - t \\
\ell_5(t) &= \frac{1}{120} t^5 - \frac{1}{6} t^4 + t^3 - 2 t^2 + t \\
\end{align}$$

Mathematica evaluates the integral as $3084$.

Comment: it would be fine if you would formulate the referenced theorem in an appropriate way here.

Answer (score 4):

We approach via inclusion-exclusion using the events:  no $A$'s are adjacent, no $B$'s are adjacent, no $R$'s are adjacent, labeled as events $\chi_a,\chi_b,\chi_r$ respectively.  Let $S$ be the universal event, the set of ways of arranging letters in `abracadabra`.

We are trying to count $|\chi_a\cap \chi_b\cap \chi_r|$

$|\chi_a\cap \chi_b\cap \chi_r| = |S\setminus(\chi_a^c\cup \chi_b^c\cup \chi_r^c)| = |S|-|\chi_a^c\cup \chi_b^c\cup \chi_r^c|$

$=|S|-|\chi_a^c|-|\chi_b^c|-|\chi_r^c|+|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_b^c|+|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_r^c| + |\chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c| - |\chi_a^c\cap \chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c|$

From earlier work, you already found $|S|=\binom{11}{5,2,2,1,1}=\frac{11!}{5!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!}$ correctly.

We ask ourselves, how do we calculate each of the remaining terms?  For $|\chi_a^c|$, the question is how many arrangements of `abracadabra` have at least two $A$'s adjacent.  The $A$'s present the most difficult problem to us in each of these terms since there are so many of them, so to continue, let us ask instead how many *don't*.  We know afterall that $|\chi_a|+|\chi_a^c|=|S|$.

In counting $|\chi_a|$, let us arrange the not-$A$ letters.  I.e. arrange the letters in the word `brcdbr`.  There are $\binom{6}{2,2,1,1}=\frac{6!}{2!\cdot 2!}$ such arrangements (using similar techniques as before).  Now that we have those letters arranged, give a bit of extra space to each side of every letter to make room for the $A$'s if one happens to be placed there.  From the $7$ available spaces (*remember to count to the far left and to the far right as well*) pick five of them to be occupied by the $A$'s.  In doing so, we guarantee that the $A$'s are not adjacent.  There are $\binom{7}{5}$ ways to complete this step.  Conclude then using multiplication principle that there are $\binom{6}{2,2,1,1}\binom{7}{5}$ to complete this process.  Convince yourself that this process counts *every* arrangement where no $A$'s are adjacent exactly once.  Thus, $|\chi_a|=\binom{6}{2,2,1,1}\binom{7}{5}$ and $|\chi_a^c| = \binom{11}{5,2,2,1,1}-\binom{6}{2,2,1,1}\binom{7}{5}$

Counting $|\chi_b^c|$ is easier since $|\chi_b^c|$ is the set of arrangements where the $B$'s are adjacent.  To count this, simply glue the two $b$'s together, perhaps like this: $~^b\!b$, and treat them like they were a single letter.  Via similar methods to the original problem, there are $\binom{10}{5,2,1,1,1}=\frac{10!}{5!\cdot 2!}$ arrangements.  Counting $|\chi_r^c|$ is the same.

Counting $|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_b^c|$ becomes a challenge again, but the method is the same as counting $|\chi_a^c|$.  We recognize that $|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_b^c| + |\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c|=|\chi_b^c|$, and counting $|\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c|$ is more manageable.  We use the same trick as before by gluing the $b$'s together, then arranging the not-$A$ letters, and then picking spaces for the $A$'s from those available, arriving at $|\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c| = \binom{5}{2,1,1,1}\binom{6}{5}$ implying $|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_b^c| = |\chi_b^c|-|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_b^c| = \binom{10}{5,2,1,1,1}-\binom{5}{2,1,1,1}\binom{6}{5}$.  Counting $|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_r^c|$ is identical.

Counting $|\chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c|$ we use a similar technique as the others by gluing the $b$'s together and gluing the $r$'s together and arranging.

Finally, counting $|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c|$ we recognize that $|\chi_a^c\cap \chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c|+|\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c| = |\chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c|$.  We use the exact same method as the previous times involving $A$'s, this time having to glue the $b$'s together and the $r$'s together before arranging everything.

Completing all necessary arithmetic will present the answer.

---

Having gone through the effort and seeing all of the cancellations going on, I recognize a slightly more efficient way: (*calculation of the terms is same as above*)

$|\chi_a^c\cup \chi_b^c\cup \chi_r^c| = |\chi_a^c|+|\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c| + |\chi_a\cap \chi_r^c| -|\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c|$  (*this can be seen via a venn-diagram argument*)

$=|S|-|\chi_a| +2|\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c| -|\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c|$ (*using the symmetry of the cases of $b$'s and $r$'s*)

So, $|\chi_a\cap \chi_b\cap \chi_r| = |\chi_a| - 2|\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c| + |\chi_a\cap \chi_b^c\cap \chi_r^c|$

> $=21\cdot 6!/4 - 2\cdot 5!/2\cdot 6 + 4! = 3084$

Answer (score 1):

A Python 3 program that generates the permutations and counts the valid ones. I debugged it until it printed the value calculated by @JMoravitz. So I hope it now contains only negligible bugs.

```
s='abracadabra'
s=sorted(s)  #converts the string to a list and sorts it
count=0 # number of valid permutations
perm=0  # number of all permutation
increased=True
while increased:
    perm+=1
    # if this is a valid permutation 
    # ("no identical characters one next to the other")
    # then count it
    if increased: 
        valid=True
        for i in range(0,len(s)-1):
            if s[i]==s[i+1]:
                valid=False
                break
        if valid:
            count+=1
    # from the right find the first position where 
    # its right neighbor has a higher value
    # replace the substring (from this position to the end)
    # by the substring made of the same characters but following 
    # in lexical order the current substring
    increased=False
    for i in range(len(s)-1,0,-1):
        if s[i]>s[i-1]:
            maxchar=s[i]
            idxmax=i
            for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
                if s[j]>s[i-1]:
                    if s[j]<maxchar:
                        maxchar=s[j]
                        idxmax=j
            # swap the values and sort the remaining list
            s[idxmax]=s[i-1]
            s[i-1]=maxchar
            s[i:]=sorted(s[i:])
            increased=True
            break
print(count, perm)
```

Its output is

```
3084 83160
```

So there are 83160 different permutations and 3084 of them satisfy the constraint.